# How to get sum of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$ using mathematical induction

Tags: induction, geometric-progressions

Prehistory: I'm reading book. Because of exercises, reading process is going very slowly. Anyway, I want honestly complete all exercises.
Theme in the book is mathematical induction. There were examples, where were shown how with mathematical induction prove equations like $(1+q)(1+q^2)(1+q^4)\dots(1+q^{{2}^{n}}) = \frac{1-q^{{2}^{n+1}}}{1-q}$.

Now I'm trying to complete exercise where I have to find sum of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$.
I tried to do it with mathematical induction. Like this:
n=1: $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

n=2: $\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{1+1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$

n=3: $\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^3}=\frac{(1+x^2)^2+2+x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}$

...

And so on (I've calculated til n=5). But I don't see any consistent pattern to evaluate sum of progression.

After that I found formulas of geometrical progression:
$q=\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ and $S_n=\frac{b_1(1-q^n)}{1-q}$, so I've evaluated:
$q=\frac{\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}}{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

and

$S_n=\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{1+X^2}\right)^n\right]\right):\left(1-\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right]\right)=\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^{n+1}\right]\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}=\frac{\left[1-\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}\right)^{n+1}\right]}{x^2}$

First of all, I'd like to know how to find sum of geometrical progression with mathematical induction.
Secondly, I'd like to know what is wrong with my evaluations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $n$ in your calculations(which are right but missed the right trick) use the following:

first set
$${{S}_{n}}=q+{{q}^{2}}+\ldots +{{q}^{n}}$$
then
$$q{{S}_{n}}={{q}^{2}}+{{q}^{3}}+\ldots +{{q}^{n+1}}$$
al last
$$\begin{align}
  & {{S}_{n}}-q{{S}_{n}}=q-{{q}^{n+1}} \\ 
 & {{S}_{n}}=\frac{q\left( 1-{{q}^{n}} \right)}{\left( 1-q \right)} \\ 
\end{align}$$

Comment: My thoughts before were wrong. Both Bernard and Mohammad Riazi-Kermani were right. In the book $q+q^2+\dots+q^n=\frac{q(1-q^n)}{1-q}$ was given without explanation. It was proven with mathematical induction and after that was shawn, just the same way, like @logo showed, how equation was got. As I understood there is no way to get sum of geometrical progression with mathematical induction.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

For a geometric series with ratio $q$:
$$q+q^2+\dots+q^n=\frac{q(1-q^n)}{1-q}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question is a little bit wider.
Firstly, in my researches $b_1=q$ so my $\frac{b_1(1-q^n)}{1-q}$ is equal to $\frac{q(1-q^n)}{1-q}$.
Secondly my questions are about mathematical induction and my own evaluations.

Comment: Well, re-prove the formula for the geometric series. There is only a difference in notation: $\frac1{1+x^2}$ for $q$. The only thing it adds is that  it converges when $n\to\infty$, as $1+x^2>1$, so $q=\frac1{1+x^2}<1$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for hint. Later I'll try to do what you told me to do.

Answer (score 1):

You like to prove $$q+q^2+\dots+q^n=\frac{q(1-q^n)}{1-q}.$$ using Mathematical induction.

The expression is true for $n=1$ because it is simply $q=q$

If true for n, you want to show that it is also true for $n+1$

Note that $$  q+q^2+\dots+q^n+q^{n+1} = \frac{q(1-q^n)}{1-q} + q^{n+1} = $$

$$ \frac {q(1-q^n)+(1-q)q^{n+1}}{1-q}=  \frac {q(1-q^{n+1})}{1-q} $$

With $q= \frac {1}{1+x^2}$ the expression under question simplifies to  $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}+…+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}=\frac {(1+x^2)^n-1}{x^2(1+x^2)^n}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I think that @Bernard hint is more useful. I think that in this exercise I had to get with my own mind till $q+q^2+\dots+q^n=\frac{q(1-q^n)}{1-q}.$ and not to use existing expression. So I'll try to step back and find out how with mathematical induction get till $q+q^2+\dots+q^n=\frac{q(1-q^n)}{1-q}.$